# Virtual Machine and local net

Tags: virtual-machine, local-network

I have Windows 7 on my PC. VMware Workstation was installed on it. I run Windows Server 2008 on virtual machine. My PC is connected to local network. I can ping all computers in local network from virtual machine and my PC. BUT nobody is able to connect to virtual machine. Please, help me to set up the access to my virtual machine from local network

Comment: This question is more appropriate for server fault, but before it is migrated, my 2 cents: check both Win7 and Win2008 firewalls.

Comment: I deactivated both firewalls, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to check:

- how did you configure the networkt in the VM? You need either bridged
  or NAT + port forwarding (for starters, use bridged - easier to set up).
- ensure the firewall of your VM allows incoming traffic on the port(s) you need

Comment: In VMWare Workstation, open the properties for your Virtual machine - there is a point called Network (or similar). Change this to bridged, and configure your (virtual) network interface in Windows Server 2008 accordingly (either by choosing a static IP from your local network or by using DHCP).